# using php file handling in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, file-handling

hi im pretty new in using file handling so what im trying to do is open a docx file then put it into a string that i will be displaying in my view. I have read that PHP file handling is already in the core of php so i wanted to try to integrate it into laravel 4.2 so here is my controller

```
public function open($id)
{
    $title = "Open files";
```

`

```
    $smpl = DB::table('sfiles')
            ->where('fileid' , '=' , $id)
            ->get();

    foreach($smpl as $file)

    $fname = $file->filename;

    $opendoc = file_get_contents('public/upload/docs/' . $fname);

    return View::make('dmy.open_doc' , compact('title', 'smpl'));
}`
```

when executed , im having an error saying

```
file_get_contents(public/upload/docs/2016-05-11-10-09-55-ppd-jobdesc.docx): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

any ideas on what iam doing wrong? or any ideas to improve my logic? thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `asset` function that will point a path to your public asset like this:

```
$opendoc = file_get_contents(asset('upload/docs/' . $fname));
```

Comment: `asset` is bad in this example. Why? Script trying to access LOCAL file, but use REMOTE route. What is the point to open another connection and call web service application? The right way is to use `public_path` in this situation. Also it will be helpful for testing, when You are not running web service.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access relative path. You have to use absolute path.

Replace this line:

```
$opendoc = file_get_contents('public/upload/docs/' . $fname);
```

with this one:

```
$opendoc = file_get_contents(public_path('upload/docs/' . $fname));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!